# Property of uniform convergence to a continuous function

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $\{ f_n \}$ be arbitrary real valued functions and $f$ be a real valued continuous function on a metric space $\mathcal{X}$. Then, is it true that $f_n ( s ) \to f( s )$ uniformly in $s$ iff for every $s \in \mathcal{X}$ and every sequence $\{ s_n \} \subset \mathcal{X}$ with $s_n \to s$, $f_n( s_n ) \to f( s )$?

If it is true, how to prove it? And if it is not true, what would be a counter-example?

It is easy to show that $f_n ( s ) \to f( s )$ uniformly in $s$ implies that for every $s \in \mathcal{X}$ and every sequence $\{ s_n \} \subset \mathcal{X}$ with $s_n \to s$, $f_n( s_n ) \to f( s )$. This is because $| f_n( s_n ) - f( s ) | \le | f_n( s_n ) - f( s_n ) | + | f( s_n ) - f( s ) | \le \sup_t | f_n( t ) - f( t ) | + | f( s_n ) - f( s ) | \to 0$ when $s_n \to s$. But is the other part true? In fact, the other part can be proved if $\mathcal{X}$ is assumed to be compact, using the property of sequential compactness. But how does one prove it for general metric spaces?

Comment: Giving either a confirmation or counterexample would completely destroy the purpose of that exercise, no?

Comment: Well have you tried *anything*?

Comment: Of course, @Lorago, I am not posting here without trying to prove it myself. It is easy to prove the $\implies$ part, but I couldn't do the other part. It would have been more helpful if you could add some direction on how to prove it (or give counter-example) than wondering whether I tried at all.

Comment: It is a bit presumptuous to assume it is an exercise, @user10354138, and it is not. Would be helpful if you can add something substantive.

Comment: Sure, it would be helpful for you if I gave you some directions, but it would also be helpful for everyone else if you included what you've tried already. You're likely to get your question closed if you don't include much more than just the problem statement

Comment: Anyways perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275755/a-sequence-of-functions-converges-uniformly-if-and-only-if-for-each-sequence) is useful

Comment: @Lorago Thanks for the link, but unfortunately it didn't help. The assertion in the link is quite straight-forward, but I can't see how that can be used here.

Comment: This is your reminder to always test out your claim on the simple cases. The statement is false.  Take $\mathcal{X}$ to be the discrete metric space on $\mathbb{N}$, and define the functions $f,f_n:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$  given by $f(s):=0$ and

$$f_n(s):=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }s=n\\
0&\text{if }s\ne n\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @C-RAM Thanks for the comment, it is interesting. You might add it as an answer. Would the assertion be true if $\mathcal{X}$ is the Euclidean metric space?

Comment: I'll see about writing an answer after tonight... I need to sleep.

Comment: @C-RAM Sorry my bad I didn't see that your example trivially extends to the Euclidean space. This assertion, while looking like an elementary textbook exercise, is in fact not, and an influential paper based their theory on it. I might add an answer based on your example to include this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is in fact false whenever $\mathcal{X}$ is not compact. To see this, note that for $\mathcal{X}$ not compact, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset\mathcal{X}$ with no accumulation points. Now we define the following functions $f,f_n:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, given by $f(s):=0$ and

$$f_n(s):=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if } s= x_n\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Suppose that $s\in\mathcal{X}$ and $\{s_n\}\subset\mathcal{X}$ are arbitrary such that $s_n\rightarrow s$. Since $x_n$ has no accumulation points then there exists some $N\geq 0$ such that $s_n\ne x_n$ for all $n\geq N$ (otherwise $s$ would be an accumulation point of $x_n$). Therefore $f_n(s_n)=0=f(s)$ for all $n\geq N$, meaning $f_n(s_n)\rightarrow f(s)$.

However, notice that $f_n(x_n)=1$ for all $n\geq 0$, so $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly.

Comment: Thanks for the rigorous proof :)

Comment: The disproved assertion was used to base the theory upon in the influential paper by Sweeting (Sweeting, T. J. (1980). Uniform asymptotic normality of the maximum likelihood estimator. The Annals of Statistics, 1375-1381) in section 4, page 1377. The implication of this disproved assertion on the subsequent theory in Sweeting's paper and the literature based on it remains to be seen.